# Date.addDays not working in a loop

Tags: date, loop

I have this code that creates opportunities for every day given a period start and end date. However I see that the addDays is not working as the resulting value is the same as the start date.

Why would this be the case?

I have attached the debug log.

Thanks!
[image]

```
                            
String fst =  nd.Funding_Stream__c;
                            Date startDate = nd.Start_Date__c;
                            Integer startyear = startDate.year();
                            Integer startmonth = startDate.month();
                            Integer startday = startDate.day();
                            
                            Date endDate = Date.newInstance(2022, 03, 31);
                            Date datetracker = Date.newInstance(startyear, startmonth, startday);  
                            Date novStart = Date.newInstance(2019, 11, 1);
                            String accName = nd.Account__r.Name;  
                                                              
                                if(startDate > start2020 ){
                                    for(date d=datetracker; d <= endDate; d=datetracker.addDays(1)) {
                                       System.debug('Date tracker' + datetracker);
                                        Integer loopMonth = datetracker.month();
                                        Integer loopYear = datetracker.year();
                                        Integer loopDay = datetracker.day();
                                        Integer numberOfDays = Date.daysInMonth(loopYear,loopMonth);

                                        Opportunity o = new Opportunity(Funding_Stream__c = fst ,AccountId = nd.Account__c, Name = accName+' - '+ fst + ' Funding Stream '+monthNameMap.get(loopMonth)+'-'+loopDay+'-'+ loopYear,RecordTypeId=OppNDBedNightRTId, StageName ='New',CloseDate= datetracker, Amount=FStoAmount.get(fst)/numberOfDays, New_Direction__c = ndId);
                                        NewDirections.add(o);
                                        NDrecordsProcessed++;
                                        if(NDrecordsProcessed == 10){
                                            break;
                                        }
                                        

                                    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `addDays()` method (and the other `add<thing>()` methods too) do not modify the date instances that they're called on.

`d = datetracker.addDays(1)` leaves `datetracker` unmodified.

What you should be doing here is adding days to your "d" loop variable (and using `d` instead of `datetracker` inside of your loop).

`for(date d = datetracker; d <= endDate; d = d.addDays(1)) {`

Comment: Oh my gosh! Such a silly mistake. Thank you so much!